# useParams for apollo GraphQL query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have an issue with my code with react and Apollo Client, i cant get the id in my URL (useParam) and put in my query for apollo i tried lot of possibilities but i cant find the right one.

If you have the right one it will be perfect ;)

i think the react router part is ok but the problem is to pass the id in my query with apollo , i'am a new graphql user... cool but not easy to understand directkly the concept

```
const GET_MEETING_ACCESS = gql`
query {
    meeting (id:$id){
      protectedAccess
      
    }
  }
`;


export default function MeetingAccessPage() {
    let { id } = useParams();
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_MEETING_ACCESS, {
        variables: { id:id },
          });

    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center h-screen w-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-600 to-purple-500 bg-gradient-to-r'>
            <div className='flex text-center h-auto p-6 flex-col h-1/3'>
                <img src={logo} alt="logo" className='flex object-fill' />
                <p className='text-white text-xl font-bold pt-6'>{data.Name}</p>
```

and here my router React

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/meeting/:id">
            <MeetingAccessPage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
```

Comment: bad query ... always test in playground before coding ... https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: yes it's the variable but when i tried in the playground and with the apollo plugin in chrome i can see the right variable number in my URL its why i dont find my issue

Comment: compare network requests... is it passed in json?

Comment: i have a 400 response. but when i put the number in the query it works perfectly

Comment: it's passed by the useQuery Apollo Client

Comment: again, test in playground using `query variables` ... query is bad (see answers) but it can work ... compare network requests (find variables on body/json - does it have a proper/passed value?) ... I hope you tested `id` in component with `console.log(id);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your query to as below

```
const GET_MEETING_ACCESS = gql`
  query Meeting($id: String){
    meeting (id:$id){
      protectedAccess
      
    }
  }
`;
```

Read more about how to use [**variables with GraphQl here**](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables)

Comment: Thanks but i dont know why i always have a 400 response...  maybe my Params url from react is not a the right place...

Comment: Do check if your graphQl queery supports a parameter. Error code 400 means it is a bad request.

Comment: Are you sure `id` is `String` or `Int`. Depending upon it you may have to parse it into integer @Desdamo?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the type of variable you use when you define the graphql query. like this ...

```
const GET_MEETING_ACCESS = gql`    
    query my_meeting($id: String!) {
       meeting (id:$id){
         protectedAccess
       }
    }
`;
```

ask me if it is not clear to you.

Comment: Thanks but i dont know why i always have a 400 response...

Comment: The above graphql query is correct. Maybe you have to check how your API server accepts and processes the query.